# Update a table with join?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I am trying to update table A with data from table B.
I thought I can do something like this

```
update A 
set A.DISCOUNT = 3 
from INVOICE_ITEMS A
join ITEM_PRICE_QUNTITY B on A.ITEM_PRICE_NO = B.ID
where A.INVOICE_ID = 33
```

but getting error
SQL Message : -104
Invalid token

can anyone help me?

Comment: just use delimeter ';' at end of the Statement

Comment: try removing `A` in `A.DISCOUNT`

Comment: Note: I have removed the _sql-server_ tag: your question is not about SQL Server (a Microsoft product), but about Firebird. Please only add relevant tags to your question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with a `JOIN`. The Firebird `UPDATE` statement has no `FROM` clause. The [syntax](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-update) is:

```
UPDATE {tablename | viewname} [[AS] alias]
   SET col = newval [, col = newval ...]
   [WHERE {search-conditions | CURRENT OF cursorname}]
   [PLAN plan_items]
   [ORDER BY sort_items]
   [ROWS <m> [TO <n>]]
   [RETURNING <values>]

<m>, <n>     ::=  Any expression evaluating to an integer.
<values>     ::=  value_expression [, value_expression ...]
<variables>  ::=  :varname [, :varname ...]
```

However the equivalent of your example query is:

```sql
update INVOICE_ITEMS 
set DISCOUNT = 3 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ITEM_PRICE_QUNTITY B WHERE B.ID = ITEM_PRICE_NO)
AND INVOICE_ID = 33
```

If you want to update using data from additional tables, you might want to consider using [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge). In your comment you ask for the equivalent query to do the following with Firebird:

```
UPDATE B 
SET B.QUANTIY = b.QUANTIY + a.QUANTITY 
FROM ITEM_PRICE_QUNTITY B JOIN INVOICE_ITEMS A ON A.ITEM_PRICE_NO = B.ID 
WHERE A.INVOICE_ID = 33
```

The equivalent `MERGE` statement would be:

```
MERGE INTO ITEM_PRICE_QUNTITY AS B
    USING INVOICE_ITEMS AS A
    ON A.ITEM_PRICE_NO = B.ID AND A.INVOICE_ID = 33
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET B.QUANTIY = B.QUANTIY + A.QUANTITY
```

Comment: can i get firebird sql for this query?(reverse version of above query) UPDATE  B
SET B.QUANTIY = b.QUANTIY + a.QUANTITY
FROM ITEM_PRICE_QUNTITY B
JOIN INVOICE_ITEMS A ON A.ITEM_PRICE_NO = B.ID
WHERE A.INVOICE_ID = 33

Answer (score 5):

From FB manual, if you are using Firebird 2.0 or above, you can use `EXECUTE BLOCK` to write a more effective statement:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE field1 type;
DECLARE VARIABLE field2 type;
-- ...etc.
DECLARE VARIABLE pk type;
BEGIN
   for select pk, field1, field2, ... from src_table
   into :pk, :field1, :field2, ...
   do update dest_table set field1 = :field1, field2 = :field2, -- ...
   where pk = :pk;
END
```

Comment: this might be a solution as well, I couldn't test your answer with my problem since the question is posted five years ago..