# Combining 2 queries in 1 (select based on other select)

Tags: sql, firebird

I have 2 queries:

```
SELECT EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS
    , EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE
    , EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP
FROM EW_OBIEKTY 
INNER JOIN EW_OB_ELEMENTY 
    ON EW_OBIEKTY.UID = EW_OB_ELEMENTY.UIDO
WHERE (((EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS)=0) AND ((EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP)<>1));
```

and second one base on first one

```
 SELECT EW_POLYLINE.P0_X, EW_POLYLINE.P0_Y, EW_POLYLINE.ID, EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY, [**result of 1st one**].IDE, EW_POLYLINE.ID_WARSTWY
FROM EW_POLYLINE LEFT JOIN [**result of 1st one**] ON EW_POLYLINE.ID = [**result of 1st one**].IDE
WHERE (((EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY)=0) AND (([**result of 1st one**].IDE) Is Null));
```

They work nice, but I need them to work as a one combined query, result from access looks like this:

```
SELECT EW_POLYLINE.ID
    , EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE
    , EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP
    , EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP
    , EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS
    , EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY
FROM (EW_POLYLINE 
        LEFT JOIN EW_OB_ELEMENTY 
            ON EW_POLYLINE.ID = EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE) 
        INNER JOIN EW_OBIEKTY 
            ON EW_OB_ELEMENTY.UIDO = EW_OBIEKTY.UID
WHERE (((EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE) Is Null) 
             AND ((EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP)<>1) 
             AND ((EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS)<>3) 
             AND ((EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY)=0));
```

But this gives me only empty table. Can you help me?

Comment: Try using a CTE (common table expression)

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `inner join` depends on the right-hand-side table of the `left join`, this effectively converts that `left join` to an `inner join`. This means that the condition `((EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE) Is Null)` will **always** be false, and your whole `where` condition evaluates to false, and the result set is therefor empty.

You need to nest the first query within the second query:

```
SELECT EW_POLYLINE.P0_X, EW_POLYLINE.P0_Y, EW_POLYLINE.ID, EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY, a.IDE, EW_POLYLINE.ID_WARSTWY
FROM EW_POLYLINE 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS
        , EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE
        , EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP
    FROM EW_OBIEKTY 
    INNER JOIN EW_OB_ELEMENTY 
        ON EW_OBIEKTY.UID = EW_OB_ELEMENTY.UIDO
    WHERE EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS = 0 AND EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP <> 1
) as a ON EW_POLYLINE.ID = a.IDE
WHERE EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY = 0 AND a.IDE Is Null
```

Or, using a [common table expression](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-cte):

```
with a as (
    SELECT EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS
        , EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE
        , EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP
    FROM EW_OBIEKTY 
    INNER JOIN EW_OB_ELEMENTY 
        ON EW_OBIEKTY.UID = EW_OB_ELEMENTY.UIDO
    WHERE EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS = 0 AND EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP <> 1
)
SELECT EW_POLYLINE.P0_X, EW_POLYLINE.P0_Y, EW_POLYLINE.ID, EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY, EW_POLYLINE.ID_WARSTWY
FROM EW_POLYLINE 
LEFT JOIN a ON EW_POLYLINE.ID = a.IDE
WHERE EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY = 0 AND a.IDE Is Null
```

Alternatively, you could reorder your joins (and replace the `left join` with a `right join`) and move some of the conditions from the where to the join clause:

```
SELECT EW_POLYLINE.P0_X, EW_POLYLINE.P0_Y, EW_POLYLINE.ID, EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY, EW_POLYLINE.ID_WARSTWY
FROM EW_OBIEKTY 
INNER JOIN EW_OB_ELEMENTY
    ON EW_OBIEKTY.UID = EW_OB_ELEMENTY.UIDO AND EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS = 0 AND EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP <> 1
RIGHT JOIN EW_POLYLINE 
   ON EW_POLYLINE.ID = EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE
WHERE EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY = 0 AND EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE Is Null
```

You can also change the evaluation order of your joins by moving parentheses from the first join to the second and move some conditions from the where to join condition:

```
SELECT EW_POLYLINE.P0_X, EW_POLYLINE.P0_Y, EW_POLYLINE.ID, EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY, EW_POLYLINE.ID_WARSTWY
FROM EW_POLYLINE 
LEFT JOIN (EW_OB_ELEMENTY 
  INNER JOIN EW_OBIEKTY 
    ON EW_OB_ELEMENTY.UIDO = EW_OBIEKTY.UID 
       AND EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP <> 1 
       AND EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS <> 3)
  ON EW_POLYLINE.ID = EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE
WHERE EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE Is Null 
AND EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY = 0
```

Yet another possibility would be to use a [`not exists`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-exists)-predicate:

```
SELECT EW_POLYLINE.P0_X, EW_POLYLINE.P0_Y, EW_POLYLINE.ID, EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY, a.IDE, EW_POLYLINE.ID_WARSTWY
FROM EW_POLYLINE
WHERE EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY = 0 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM EW_OBIEKTY 
    INNER JOIN EW_OB_ELEMENTY 
        ON EW_OBIEKTY.UID = EW_OB_ELEMENTY.UIDO
    WHERE EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS = 0 AND EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP <> 1
    AND EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE = EW_POLYLINE.ID
)
```

This last one is probably best because it is - in my opinion - more self-explanatory than the other ones as it more clearly shows what you are querying for (rows from `EW_POLYLINE` that don't have rows (`not exists`) that meet a certain condition).

Comment: I'll analize all of your solutions, this will be very usefull, Thanks.

Comment: What should I do if I want to update "stan_zmiany" to 3 for selected  elements? I tried UPDATE EW_POLYLINE LEFT JOIN (SELECT EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS
        , EW_OB_ELEMENTY.IDE
        , EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP
    FROM EW_OBIEKTY 
    INNER JOIN EW_OB_ELEMENTY 
        ON EW_OBIEKTY.UID = EW_OB_ELEMENTY.UIDO
    WHERE EW_OBIEKTY.STATUS = 0 AND EW_OB_ELEMENTY.TYP <> 1
)  AS a ON EW_POLYLINE.ID = a.IDE SET EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY = 3
WHERE (((EW_POLYLINE.STAN_ZMIANY)=0) AND ((a.IDE) Is Null)); and it did not work, as well as adding update at the end of first solution.

Comment: @batonico First look if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800340/update-a-table-with-join answers your question. If not, please ask a new question for that; it is considerably different from this and comments are not a good venue for asking questions.