# Update child field with parent field if child's field is NULL

Tags: firebird

I've two tables `PURCHASE_ORDER_HDR` and `PURCHASE_ORDER_DET`. Linked with key `POH_ID`.

Both Header and Detail table contains `DELIVERYDATE` where detail's Delivery Date can be null.

I want to update `PURCHASE_ORDER_DET` with Header's Delivery Date where Detail's Delivery Date is `NULL`

Tried the something like following, which is not syntactically correct.

```
UPDATE PURCHASE_ORDER_DET pod
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT poh.POH_ID as parentId,
           poh.DELIVERYDATE as dlvDate
    FROM PURCHASE_ORDER_HDR poh 
) parent on pod.POH_ID = parent.parentId
SET 
    pod.DELIVERYDATE = parent.dlvDate
WHERE 
    pod.DELIVERYDATE = null
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by Mark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800340/update-a-table-with-join), I tried the following with it's equivalent `MERGE` statement.

```
UPDATE pod
SET pod.DELIVERYDATE = poh.DELIVERYDATE
FROM PURCHASE_ORDER_DET pod JOIN PURCHASE_ORDER_HDR poh ON poh.POH_ID = pod.POH_ID
WHERE pod.DELIVERYDATE = null
```

The equivalent `MERGE` statement is

```
MERGE INTO PURCHASE_ORDER_DET AS pod 
    USING PURCHASE_ORDER_HDR AS poh
    ON poh.POH_ID = pod.POH_ID AND pod.DELIVERYDATE = NULL 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET pod.DELIVERYDATE = poh.DELIVERYDATE
```

It does execute but no row get effected.

Comment: That is a syntactically invalid statement. Exactly what is your question?

Comment: Maybe this question answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800340/update-a-table-with-join or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318913/updating-selected-rows-in-firebird

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel . Yeah! query give syntactical error. I've also tried the `MERGE` but it doesn't do the trick. Just edited the question with my try with merge. *Exactly what is your question?* I want to update pod.deliveryDate with poh.deliveryDate if pod.deliveryDate = null

Comment: The condition `pod.DELIVERYDATE = null` is always false in SQL as nulls are special. You need to use `pod.DELIVERYDATE is null`. This might be why your other two attempts don't work (and otherwise, I'll give it a closer look later).

Comment: Ahhh... My bad. Missed that.

Comment: that is why FB now has `x IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM y` condition too :-D

Comment: Also it could be wide to do divide et empera and check before change. I mean before you do `update ... where ...` do `select * ... where ...` just to see if the rows subset you would be changing is exactly what you wanted, not too much, not too few. Because stupid errors like `delete ... where x=x or y=z` are way too easy to do in SQL. In your case would you just issue `select * from pod where pod.DELIVERYDATE = null` - you would instantly see your problem has no relation to `update` and would immediately look into the source of the problem (where clause) instead of wondering where to look.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel perhaps nitpicking, but it is not true that `condition pod.DELIVERYDATE = null is always false in SQL` !!! it is always `null` not always `false`. Granted, inside **simplistic** WHERE clause all that matters is that it is not `TRUE`, however under that misconception one can easily be bitten with queries like `select * from rdb$database where  not (1=null)`, for example `...where ((condition_1) and (field=null)) or ((condition_2) and not (field=null))` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Mark, This worked for me.

```
MERGE INTO PURCHASE_ORDER_DET AS pod 
    USING PURCHASE_ORDER_HDR AS poh
    ON poh.POH_ID = pod.POH_ID AND pod.DELIVERYDATE is NULL 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET pod.DELIVERYDATE = poh.DELIVERYDATE
```